# How do I wrap this BAIL macro in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, debugging, macros

I use this little snippet to halt my iPhone app in the simulator.

```
NSAssert((0), @"Bail early while testing");
```

When I try to make it a #defined macro like this:

```
#define BAILNOW (NSAssert((0), @"Bail early while testing"))
```

I get this build error:

> error: expected expression before 'do'

It seems to be related to the nesting of the NSAssert() macro but I'm at a loss as to how to get around it. Should I dig into the  NSAssertionHandler docs or is there some simpler way to halt the app in it's tracks? Or should I just set a breakpoint and get on with my life?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define BAILNOW NSAssert(0, @"Bail early while testing")
```

Just remove the brackets and this will succesfully be compiled. But I dont test the code in runtime.